# Why is Mac Mail refusing a correct password?

Tags: mail.app, password, bug

Recently Mac Mail started requesting the password for my MSN mail account and refusing the correct password when entered. I'm 100% certain the password is correct (I've used to to log in on iOS in Mail and Outlook, and on macOS in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox). Only Apple's Mail client is refusing the password.

What could cause Apple Mail to refuse a correct password that's accepted everywhere else?

Comment: Does the password currently work in other clients like Outlook when using the same protocol (POP or IMAP). Maybe only POP is enabled and you are trying to set it up as an IMAP account or POP/IMAP is disabled on the MSN account.

Comment: @KevinGrabher It’s IMAP on macOS. I’m not sure what it is on iOS (that info is not available in settings). I’ve changed nothing in any settings since it was working. I’m not trying to set it up.

Comment: It still works and updates on your iOS device? To get the Account Type on iOS in Settings > Mail > Accounts tap your Account, at the very top it should state POP/IMAP/Exchange

Comment: @KevinGrabher Yes, works fine on iOS. It just says “Outlook”.

Comment: I've known Mail do this with an Outlook account. It asks for the password & doesn't say it's wrong but says in red something like 'couldn't confirm' [I cannot remember the wording, it's not that, but it's not 'wrong password'.] I can still get into the web version using the same pass. I found I could clear it by switching off the account [uncheck the Enable box] , relaunching Mail then re-enabling.

Comment: @Tetsujin "Unable to verify account name or password". I tried the disable, relaunch, enable cycle a few times. Also a few for quits and termination of all processes mentioning "mail", but no change.

Answer (score 1):

I’d start with the connection doctor to see details:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-connection-doctor-mlhlp1189/mac

Hard to guess where your setup or config is off without some details.

Comment: It just says: "Unable to verify account name or password" like the error message in the login dialog.

Comment: @orome Have you enabled the "Log Connection Activity" option and viewed that log file? It should contain the detailed message from the server.